# Google Script CSV Downloader Project - How to specify Folder

Tags: google-apps-script, export-to-csv, google-sheets-api

I have been working on creating a script to allow employees in our shipping department to operate more efficiently. We use a barcode scanner to generate a CSV file - we use the following script  to specify cells for the CSV; I'm looking to improve this so that the file is saved in a specific folder for easy sharing.

```
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var searchMenuEntries = [ {name: "Search in all files", functionName: "search"}];
  var csvMenuEntries = [{name: "Save as CSV file", functionName: "saveAsCSV"},
                      {name: "Load from CSV file", functionName: "importFromCSV"}];
  ss.addMenu("Search Google Drive", searchMenuEntries);
  ss.addMenu("CSV", csvMenuEntries);
}
function saveAsCSV() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Primary Time');
  // append ".csv" extension to the sheet name
  // Prompts the user for the file name
  var fileName = Browser.inputBox("Save CSV file as (e.g. myCSVFile):");
 
  // Check that the file name entered wasn't empty
  if (fileName.length !== 0) {
    // Add the ".csv" extension to the file name
    fileName = fileName + ".csv";
    // Convert the range data to CSV format
    var csvFile = convertRangeToCsvFile_(fileName);
    // Create a file in Drive with the given name, the CSV data and MimeType (file type)
    DriveApp.createFile(fileName, csvFile, MimeType.CSV);
    
  else {
    Browser.msgBox("Error: Please enter a CSV file name.");
  }
}

function convertRangeToCsvFile_(csvFileName) {
  // Get the selected range in the spreadsheet
  var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSelection();
  try {
    var data = ws.getValues();
    var csvFile = undefined;
 
    // Loop through the data in the range and build a string with the CSV data
    if (data.length > 1) {
      var csv = "";
      for (var row = 0; row < data.length; row++) {
        for (var col = 0; col < data[row].length; col++) {
          if (data[row][col].toString().indexOf(",") != -1) {
            data[row][col] = "\"" + data[row][col] + "\"";
          }
        }
 
        // Join each row's columns
        // Add a carriage return to end of each row, except for the last one
        if (row < data.length-1) {
          csv += data[row].join(",") + "\r\n";
        }
        else {
          csv += data[row];
        }
      }
      csvFile = csv;
    }
    return csvFile;
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
    Browser.msgBox(err);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**I have 2 options for you:**

1. Use [File.moveTo(destination)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#movetodestination) to move your newly created file to your target folder.

**Sample code:**

```
function option1(){
  var targetFolderId ='1QHe2zCebXBZxiplAfVZpO1dhxxxx';
  var csvFile = "Sample Content";
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(targetFolderId);
  var file = DriveApp.createFile("SampleFile1.csv", csvFile, MimeType.CSV);
  file.moveTo(folder);
}
```

---

2. Use [Advanced Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive) to create a file within a specific parent folder

**Sample Code:**

```
function option2(){
  var targetFolderId ='1QHe2zCebXBZxiplAfVZpO1dhxxxx';
  var content = "Sample Content";

  var resource = {
    title: "SampleFile2.csv",
    mimeType: "text/csv",
    parents: [{id:targetFolderId}]
  }
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(content,"text/csv");
  var file = Drive.Files.insert(resource,blob);
  Logger.log(file);

}
```

### Output:

[image: ![enter image description here]